# Lets Encrypt, Cloudflare, and Wildcard SSL

Tags: ssl, cloudflare, lets-encrypt

I have been trying to achieve wildcard SSL for my app where I need HTTPS for all the dynamic subdomain and I have been trying almost all the tuts found on the internet and almost all way is either giving redirect loop or not working. I am trying this for almost 2 days now and have totally no idea how to go forward. I tried it using certbot doing acme-challenge, DNS Cloudflare plugins but nothing worked for me. Please guide me.

Comment: It's been a while since I used letsencrypt, I don't remember making DNS entries for it. However, it may help that any verification DNS entries you make in cloudflare must be "Not Proxied" / Grey clouded entries to resolve correctly

Comment: What do you mean by `redirect loop`? How can verifying domain give you `redirect loop`? There is currently two option to verify your domain, DNS TXT record or upload TXT file to your server. This question in its current form is not answerable, consider editing it or reading the FAQ.

Answer (score 0):

Let's Encrypt supports wildcard SSL certificate only via [DNS-01 challenge.](https://letsencrypt.org/docs/faq/#does-let-s-encrypt-issue-wildcard-certificates)

> Yes. Wildcard issuance must be done via ACMEv2 using the DNS-01 challenge. See this post for more technical information.

If you use [dehydrated](https://github.com/dehydrated-io/dehydrated), I can recommend [cfhookbash](https://github.com/sineverba/cfhookbash), which is a hook for [dehydrated](https://github.com/dehydrated-io/dehydrated).

```
./dehydrated -c -d *.example.com -t dns-01 -k '${PATH_WHERE_YOU_CLONED_CFHOOKBASH}/cfhookbash/hook.sh'
```

Comment: Thank you for the hint, cfhookbash developer here :)